# NotePad++ Currency RegEx with Optional Replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

My Search pattern: `\"(\$)(\d{0,3}?)\,?(\d{1,3}?)\,?(\d{0,3})\s?\"`

Matches all of these:

```
"$1"
"$10"
"$100"
"$1,000"
"$10,000 "
"$100,000"
"$1,000,000 "
"$10,000,000"
"$100,000,000"
```

I know I don't really need to search for under the thousands place, but am including those for possible future application.

My problem: I need to replace all of the commas with HTML escape char `&#44;`, but only if there is a comma present in the search result.

This replace pattern `$1$2&#44;$3&#44;$4` gives the incorrect result, and I'm just not seeing the right pattern to use for my replacement.

```
$&#44;1&#44;
$&#44;1&#44;0
$&#44;1&#44;00
$&#44;1&#44;000
$&#44;10&#44;000
$&#44;100&#44;000
$1&#44;000&#44;000
$10&#44;000&#44;000
$100&#44;000&#44;000
```

This is the result I am attempting to get:

```
$1
$10
$100
$1&#44;000
$10&#44;000
$100&#44;000
$1&#44;000&#44;000
$10&#44;000&#44;000
$100&#44;000&#44;000
```

No Quotes and no extra space after the last digit.

I'm not married to having to find the 1's through 100's, but it is preferable.

Any ideas on how to do optional replace in NotePad++?

Comment: In one line: _Look for , in number and replace with `&#44`_ Right ?

Comment: Search for `(?<=\d),(?=\d)`, replace with `&#44;` ?

Comment: @SebastianProske: I guess that would be all. :D

Comment: Thanks @SebastianProske. That works great for finding the commas. I was a little unclear in what I wanted to accomplish. My fault. I have to remove the quotes and the occasional space after the last digit. Still struggling with that. I could run a few passes for different matches, but if I can do it in one pass that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex Search and Replace: Replace `(\d),(\d)` with `\1&#44;\2`. Check regular expression, click Replace or Replace all.

For some unknown reason, the RE of Sebastian from the comments above did not work with notepad++ 6.8.6 (find worked fine, but not replace). So instead of using look around, we capture the surrounding digits into `\1` and `\2` for reuse in the replacement.

Comment: ▲ for simple and smart.

Comment: My solution is working fine in v 6.9, just tested it.

Comment: @SebastianProske The funny thing is, that it finds all the commas when clicking find, but it just did not replace. Must be time for an update.

Comment: @Lars Fischer, this works fine if I am just trying to replace the commas. I was a little unclear in what I wanted to accomplish. My fault. I have to remove the quotes and the occasional space after the last digit. Still struggling with that. I could run a few passes for different matches, but if I can do it in one pass that would be ideal.

Comment: @MarkMiller You could do a first regex find/replace step, finding `"(\$[\d,]+)[ ]*"` replacing with `\1`, then do the replacement of commas in the answer as second step.

Comment: Thanks @Lars Fischer. That works very well. I appreciate everyone's great advice and expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Try following regex:

```
(?<=\d),(?=\d)
```

After running test on your dataset, I got result as:

```
"$1"
"$10"
"$100"
"$1&#44;000"
"$10&#44;000 "
"$100&#44;000"
"$1&#44;000&#44;000 "
"$10&#44;000&#44;000"
"$100&#44;000&#44;000"
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see @SebastianProske, posted same regex. All credits goes to  first poster.

Comment: Thanks @Saleem. That works great for finding the commas.  I was a little unclear in what I wanted to accomplish. My fault. I have to remove the quotes and the occasional space after the last digit. Still struggling with that. I could run a few passes for different matches, but if I can do it in one pass that would be ideal.

Comment: Unfortunately, Notepad++ doesn't support multiple regex.Either you can use some kind of scripting in python, perl etc to do this on windows. However, on *nix platform you have sed

Comment: However, you can go in two passes.  In first pass use following regex `[ "]+` to remove all quotes and extra spaces. and in 2nd pass run above regex.

Comment: Thanks @Saleem. This works equally well. Appreciate your advice and expertise.